# How do I reuse part of a schematic in multiple projects in KiCad?

Tags: kicad

I would like to re-use parts of a schematic, say a microcontroller or a voltage regulator, in multiple KiCad projects. Is it possible to copy and paste blocks between eeschema windows or can this be accomplished by another means?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create **hierarchical sheet** and place there reusable part/circuit/module, create interface pins via **hierarchical pin in sheet**. But project resides in own directory you need copy schema file with **hierarchical sheet**. When you include in project you **place hierarchical label** to connect reusable part into project circuit. Such a sheet may be even reused more times in one project and multi-unit parts are allocated correctly.

Note: Because referencing is maintained in file the file must be copied when used in second project. It's feature.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is still true!  I created a [quick write up](http://forembed.com/kicad-copy-paste.html).  Hope it is outdated soon!